# How to proof $E[(x-m')^TA(x-m')] = (m-m')^TA(m-m') + Tr(A\Sigma)$ in matrix cookbbok

Tags: matrices, expected-value, gaussian

I read the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf),

In its section 8.2.2, Eq(380). It says that
if $x$ is $N(m, \Sigma)$, then, we have

$$
E[(x-m')^TA(x-m')] = (m-m')^TA(m-m') + Tr(A\Sigma)
$$

How to proof this euqation step-by-step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $x-m' = x-m+m-m'$, we have
\begin{align}
E[(x-m')^\top A (x-m')]
&= E[(x-m)^\top A (x-m)]
 + 2 E[(m-m')^\top A (x-m)]
 + E[(m-m')^\top A (m-m')]
\end{align}

The middle term is zero since
$$E[(m-m')^\top A (x-m)]
= (m-m')^\top A E[x-m] = 0.$$

The last term is $(m-m')^\top A (m-m')$ because the expectation can be removed.

The first term is
\begin{align}
E[(x-m)^\top A (x-m)]
&= E[\text{Tr}((x-m)^\top A (x-m))]
& \text{trace of $1\times 1$ matrix is itself}
\\
&= E[\text{Tr}(A (x-m) (x-m)^\top)]
& \text{cyclic property of trace}
\\
&= \text{Tr}(A E[(x-m)(x-m)^\top])
& \text{linearity of expectation}
\\
&= \text{Tr}(A \Sigma)
& \text{definition of covariance matrix}
\end{align}